# Issue related to click listener layout when inflated multiple times

Tags: android

I am inflating a layout for four times in another layout,now I want to add click listener to few controls in the layout.when I am doing so its changing values for the last layout only rather than changing to respective layout.

public class DRSDetail extends Activity {

```
TextView changeCode;
Button generate, fromVessel, toVessel;
String strFromVessel, strToVessel, stroverTime, stroffShoreTime,
        stronShoreTime;
Spinner spinnerValues;
Date dateOne, dateTwo;
EditText overTime, offShoreTime, onShoreTime;
ArrayList<String> dataValues = new ArrayList<String>();
View layout_number;
int idValue = 10;
int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.drsdetail);

    changeCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeCode);
    generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate);

    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

    loadSpinnerData();
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout_number = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutinflate, parent,
                false);

        spinnerValues = (Spinner) layout_number
                .findViewById(R.id.spinnerValues);

        fromVessel = (Button) layout_number.findViewById(R.id.fromVessel);

        toVessel = (Button) layout_number.findViewById(R.id.toVessel);

        overTime = (EditText) layout_number.findViewById(R.id.overTimeEdit);

        offShoreTime = (EditText) layout_number
                .findViewById(R.id.offShoreEdit);

        onShoreTime = (EditText) layout_number
                .findViewById(R.id.onShoreEdit);

        row.addView(layout_number);
        parent.addView(row);
        assignClickListener(fromVessel);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDataValues = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataValues);
        adapterDataValues
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinnerValues.setAdapter(adapterDataValues);
    }

}

private void assignClickListener(final View vessel) {
    fromVessel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(DRSDetail.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0,
                                int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                            fromVessel.setText(selectedHour + ":"
                                    + selectedMinute);
                            strFromVessel = fromVessel.getText().toString();
                            System.out.println("strFromVessel"
                                    + strFromVessel);

                        }
                    }, hour, minute, true);// Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
};

private void loadSpinnerData() {
    dataValues.clear();
    try {
        System.out.println("in try");
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(DRSDetail.this);
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // project number
        Cursor crData = db.rawQuery("SELECT DRS_ID FROM  DRS_TBL", null);
        if (crData.getCount() > 0) {
            while (crData.moveToNext()) {
                dataValues.add(crData.getString(0));
                System.out.println("value of cr.getString "
                        + crData.getString(0));

            }
        }

        crData.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    }

}
```

Comment: make `fromVessel`, `toVessel`, `overTime`, `offShoreTime` and `onShoreTime` variables as local variables. Dont declare them globally.

Comment: If he did that he would not be able to refer to them inside OnClickListener because they would have to be declared final and he couldn't change them on each loop iteration.

Comment: @GregEnnis hmmmm... There is no problem with declaring them as final. and you will receive instance of a `Button` in `onClick()` as a parameter...

Comment: ugh, I think you are right. sorry didnt have my coffee

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `fromVessel` gets re-assigned every time through the loop, so in the last loop iteration it is assigned to the final view. It uses that view every time the `OnClickListener` is called - regardless of which view invoked the click listener.

What you need is a closure so that you can refer to each of your different views. You can't create a temporary variable because it would have to be declared final.

You could do something like factoring out the `setOnClickListener` into it's own function scope:

```
private void assignClickListener(final View vessel) {
   vessel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       // Time picker stuff...
   });
});
```

Comment: Just want to make sure, int he loop you are using `vessel` and not `fromVessel`. If you just copy and paste the code and left references to `fromVessel`, then yes, it would not work.

Comment: Please post the code to "assignClickListener". You should be passing the vessel, not the layout. Should be: `assignClickListener(fromVessel);`

Comment: No, you didn't make the fix I mentioned above. You need to pass fromVessel to assignClickListener. That is the fix for the problem you are having - you need to have seperate references for each of the 4 vessels in your layout. The code you updated can't possibly work. Please read my original answer carefully.

Comment: Post the entire file. Including "Time picker stuff..."

Comment: Inside `onTimeSet` you are still referring to `fromVessel`. As I stated in the comment above, you need to use the parameter `vessel` and NOT refer to `fromVessel` at all inside assignClickListener. I figured this was the problem thats why I asked you to post the whole file.

Comment: Try using Gopal solution in comments, that will be an easier change